# Center "ul" element with set width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to set an unsorted list as a "background". To do that, I have assigned it to be very wide so it matches whatever screen opens the page including 2560px width. But I can't make it center completely with CSS unless there is a trick or something. I am willing to go jquery way. Technically the ul will have the same effect as  background-position:top center;

Instead of a code I attach an image with the way it should work (added code)

```
<div style="background-color:black; width:100%; overflow:hidden; height:302px; text-align:center; position:relative">
<ul style="padding:0px; margin:0px; text-align:center; width:2560px; height:100%; margin:0 auto 0; position:relative;">
    <li class="image"></li><li class="image"></li><li class="image"></li><li class="image"></li><li class="image"></li><li class="image">

</ul>
</div>
```

i used inline css so its clearer what im trying to do.

[image]

any help appreciated

Comment: You should include code.

Comment: Does the <ul> have a set height or is the content/height of the <ul> dynamic?

Comment: ul has set height as well. the width is set as well.

Answer (score 2):

Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpnFZ/) what you want? I think you didn't explain correctly when you said "background"

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background:#FF0000;
}


ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    background:#0000FF;
    line-height:65px;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yes but i don't want any wrapping. I need the li items to just stay the way they are.

Comment: What do you mean? So that they stay next to each other no matter what?

Comment: Yup, the content on the ul is acting like a background, i dont need any wrapping. just want whatever is in the ul to just move centered along with screen resizing.

Comment: Actually it's close but i need the ONE /TWO/THREE for example to move away from the screen to the left as the screen is resized.

Comment: Imagine the ul element to be background and background position to be center; Thats the effect i am looking for

Comment: Ok. In your code you use "<li class="image"></li>" so I'm guessing you're repeating the same css... why not just use a repeated background image ? Other than that, I think you need javascript to position the elements correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to accomplish something like this?

You can absolutely position the `<ul>` in the middle of the screen using `top: 50%;` as long as you set the `margin-top` to negative half the height of the `<ul>`. For instance, if the `<ul>` height is `100px`, you'll need to set the `margin-top: -50px;` along with `top: 50%; position: absolute;` in order to perfectly vertically center the `<ul>` in the center of the screen.

If you do not know the height of the `<ul>` beforehand, I added some jQuery that will determine the height and adjust the margin-top accordingly. You can change the height of the `<div>` container on the jsFiddle to see that the `<ul>` will be centered vertically regardless of the container's height.

http://jsfiddle.net/kreCe/1/

Comment: Yes, similarly to ComputerArts below. I need the li elements to move to the left as well, I dont want the resizing to happen only to the right, i need it to happen from both sides evenly.

Comment: So... you want the <li> items to be centered horizontally as well? I added `text-align: center` to the container `<div>` to accomplish this: http://jsfiddle.net/kreCe/2/

Comment: Not sure if it works. It's quite possible what I am asking is impossible. check the image i attached on my post. you see how i have the screen resized on the second version but the UL remained centered both sides.

Comment: I think i figured it out using absolute positioning, left:50% and margin-left:-1280px;

Answer (score 0):

Just for FYI, the solution lies on display:block-inline. :) thanks for all your help